# How to remove all the unnecessary tags and signs from html files?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, xbrl

I am trying to extract "only" text information from 10-K reports (e.g. company's proxy reports) on SEC's EDGAR system by using Python's BeautifulSoup or HTMLParser. However, the parsers that I am using do not seem to work well onto the 'txt'-format files, including a large portion of meaningless signs and tags along with some xbrl information, which is not needed at all. However, when I apply the parser directly onto 'htm'-format files, which are more or less free from the issues of meaningless tags, the parser seems works relatively fine.

```
"""for Python 3, from urllib.request import urlopen"""
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

"""for extracting text data only from txt format"""
txt = urlopen("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1660156/000166015616000019/0001660156-16-000019.txt")
bs_txt = BeautifulSoup(txt.read())
bs_txt_text = bs_txt.get_text()
len(bs_txt_text) # 400051

"""for extracting text data only from htm format"""
html = urlopen("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1660156/000166015616000019/f201510kzec2_10k.htm")
bs_html = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
bs_html_text = bs_html.get_text()
len(bs_html_text) # 98042
```

But the issue is I am in a position to rely on 'txt'-format files, not on 'htm' ones, so my question is, is there any way to deal with removing all the meaningless signs and tags from the files and extracting only text information as the one directly extracted from 'htm' files? I am relatively new to parsing using Python, so if you have any idea on this, it would be of great help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: These files (both the `.txt` and the `.htm`) seem to be some sort of SGML-based thing with HTML documents embedded inside. The `.txt` seems to have a lot of HTML documents embedded, while the `.htm` has just one. You might want to try an SGML parser instead of an HTML parser.

Comment: or... apparently it's supposed to be XML-based, not SGML-based? There's a part right near the start where it says ".sgml", but [apparently it's XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBRL).

Comment: Try parsing it with an XML parser.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to deal with XBRL data is to use an XBRL processor such as the open-source [Arelle](http://arelle.org/) (note: I have no affiliation with them) or other proprietary engines.

You can then look at the data with a higher level of abstraction. In terms of the XBRL data model, the process you describe in the question involves

1. looking for concepts that are text blocks (`textBlockItemType`) in the taxonomy;
2. retrieving the value of the facts reported against these concepts in the instance;
3. additionally, obtaining some meta-information regarding it: who (reporting entity), when (XBRL period), what the text is about (concept metadata and documentation), etc.

An XBRL processor will save you the efforts of resolving the entire DTS as well as dealing with the complexity of the low-level syntax.

The second most appropriate way is to use an XML parser, maybe with an XML Schema engine as well as XQuery or XSLT, but this will require more work as you will need to either:

- look at the XML Schema (XBRL taxonomy schema) files, recursively navigating them and looking for text block concepts, deal with namespaces, links, and so on (which an XBRL processor shields you from)
- or only look at the instance, ideally the XML file (e.g., https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1660156/000166015616000019/zeci-20151231.xml ) with a few hacks (such as taking XML elements ending with `TextBlock`), but this is *at your own risks* and not recommended as this bypasses the taxonomy.

Finally, as you suggest in the original question, you can also look at the document-format files (HTML, etc) rather than at the data files of the SEC filing, however in this case it defeats the purpose of using XBRL, which is to make the data understandable by a computer thanks to tags and contexts, and it may miss important context information associated with the text -- a bit like opening a spreadsheet file with a text/hex editor.

Of course, there are use cases that could justify using that last approach such as running natural language processing algorithms. All I am saying is that this is then outside of the scope of XBRL.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [HTML tag stripper](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/detail/htmlStripper.py) at the pyparsing wiki Examples page. It does not try to build an HTML doc, it merely looks for HTML and script tags and strips them out.